# Uncompressed size of images taken with the camera phonegap

Tags: angularjs, cordova, camera, ionic-framework

I'm up to my server images, images taken from the camera of my device but the truth weigh much to be exact 5.4 MB and in very good quality. I wondered if there was some kind of parameter to be declared for the quality or at least the weight of the file is lower.

```
Camera.getPicture().then(function(imageURI) {
  $scope.imagen = imageURI;
  $scope.lastPhoto = imageURI;
  $scope.mostrar_form = true;
  $scope.mostrar_boton_view = false;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);  
  initialize();
  document.getElementById('buton_refresh').click(); 
  $( "#buton_refresh" ).trigger( "click" );
}, function() {
  $scope.mostrar_boton_view = true;
  $ionicHistory.goBack();
}, {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  allowEdit: true,
  encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true,
  correctOrientation: true
})
```

Function upload image:

```
$scope.publicarView = function(){
var server = URL_BASE+'addView/'+sessionService.get("user_id")+"/"+$scope.data.content+"/null/"+$scope.latitud+"/"+$scope.longitud+"/"+1;

var trustAllHosts = true;

var ftOptions = new FileUploadOptions();
ftOptions.fileKey = 'file';
ftOptions.fileName = $scope.imagen.substr($scope.imagen.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
ftOptions.mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
ftOptions.httpMethod = 'POST';

console.log(ftOptions);

$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(encodeURI(server), $scope.imagen, ftOptions, trustAllHosts)
.then(function(result) {
  console.log(result)
}, function(err) {
  // Error
  console.log(err);
}, function (progress) {

  });
}
```

Comment: Didn't understand the question. You want to know if you can control the quality or not right? `quality: 50,` can't you use this line to control the quality!!

Comment: Hello, excuse my English jeje. I need to know I am if I can lower the quality or resolution of the image taken by the camera. It is understood that?

Comment: You really need to do some research before posting questions here - it is expected of you. It is not hard to find out how to resize images using javascript or in any server language by doing a web search.

Comment: In fact, if you can adjust the size using javascript or on the server, I wanted to find out (and that's why I posted here) is whether the plug of the camera had some parameters to handle what I need, so how to use existing tools within the plug and not have to write more code and carry my function.

Comment: reduce the quality: 50 to quality: 25 and check the file size. It should reduce the file size and quality. Not sure, need testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova Camera plugin can be used with the following parameters :

```
var options = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit: false,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 700,
    targetHeight: 700,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    correctOrientation: true
};
```

The following parameters have impacts on the size:

```
quality: 50,
targetWidth: 700,
targetHeight: 700,
```

See official doc here : `https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera`

For exemple, my code to take a picture looks something like ;

```
var options = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit: false,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 700,
        targetHeight: 700,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        correctOrientation: true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {

        d.resolve( { "img" : imageData });

    }, function(err) {
        d.reject(err);
    });
```

Comment: Copy and paste your code, and weighs 4.2 MB image, takes too long to load up and in the application. This problem is killing me :s